# Make results of google-CSE random

Tags: java, search, google-custom-search

I'm creating a google search engine with the CSE of google. I'm trying to get one random result every time i search for a query. For example: When I search for the word "coffee" the engine returns one result, random from all the "coffee results".

Is there someone who can help me to make the result random?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you're using **Linux**, you could read from `/dev/random` as it will contain a random stream.
- For **Windows**, use [the `%RANDOM%` environment variable](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-random.html).
- **JavaScript** has a method `Math.random();` (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp)).
- **PHP** can [pick a random element from an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) with `mixed array_rand ( array $array [, int $num = 1 ] )` or [generate a random number](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) with `int rand ( int $min , int $max )`.
- **Java** can generate a random number using `new Random().nextInt(number_of_results + 1);`

Number the results (i.e. store them in an array) and use the random number to pick a result (`chosen_result = results_array[random_num];`)

If this doesn't suit your needs you will need to provide more information such as the programming language you're using for this.